# Qlik Sense. Time Filter

Tags: time, filter, qliksense

Same issue I posted Friday but I will be more specific this time. I have this data:

```
UserId  Action Id     Date
   1        1       1/1/2018
   1        2       1/1/2018
   1        2       2/1/2018
   2        3       3/1/2018
   2        4       4/1/2018
```

And I want a filter that will yield the following:

**Count Instances from FirstDate to 2/1/2018**

```
UserId    ActionCount
   1          3
   2          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data load editor you want to group by the User in order to get that first date:

```
GroupedUserData:
Load
UserId
min(Date) as FirstDate
resident [The name of your original table];
```

And then you want to use set analysis chart-side:

```
sum({<FirstDate = {'<=2/1/2018'}>} ActionCount)
```